# React Native make keyboard dismiss focus on a button press in keyboardAvoidingView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard, dismiss

I am creating a react native app to learn how to use react native. I have mostly followed this tutorial : [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgtedCTtNeU) when creating the ui of the text input. My problem is that I have a button next to an input. I also have those two components nested inside of a keyboard avoiding view. When I press send on the keyboard, I clear the input of its text and I would like to unFocus the input. It works when I press the send button on the keyboard, but when I press the react native button, which is next to the input in the app, it goes through the function to send the message and then re-focuses the input again.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Keyboard
} from 'react-native';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';



import colors from '../../styles/styles';


const INPUT_HEIGHT = 65

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {


  state = {
    message : ""
  }

  onMessageSend = () => {
    alert(this.state.message);
    this.setState({
      message : ''
    });
    Keyboard.dismiss()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <View style = {styles.messages}>
            <Text>Messages</Text>
          </View>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior = 'padding'
          //keyboardVerticalOffset = {INPUT_HEIGHT}
          enabled
          >
          <ScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps = "handled"
          >
          <View style = {styles.input}>
              <View style = {styles.inputWrapper}>
                <TextInput
                style = {styles.textInput}
                ref={ref => (this._input = ref)}
                placeholder = "Message"
                returnKeyType = "send"
                value = {this.state.message}
                onChangeText = {(text) => {this.setState({message : text})}}
                onSubmitEditing = {this.onMessageSend}
                />
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.onMessageSend}>
              <Ionicons name="ios-send" size={32} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          </ScrollView>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>


      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  messages : {
    flex : 1,
    backgroundColor : colors.green,
  },
  textInput : {
    flex : 1
  },
  input : {
    height: 65,
    backgroundColor : "#fefefe",
    bottom : 0,
    right : 0,
    left : 0,
    flexDirection : 'row',
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent : 'space-around',
    borderTopWidth : StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor : "#C1C9D3"
  },
  inputWrapper : {
    backgroundColor : "#fff",
    width: "85%",
    height: "65%",
    borderRadius : 25,
    borderWidth : StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor : "#C1C9D3",
    paddingHorizontal : 16,
  }
});



export default HomeScreen;
```

What I expected to happen was that the input would blur when I pressed the icon button and stay unfocused, but what actually happened is that the input unfocused, alerted the user, and then re-focused.

How would I make the input unfocus entirely when pressing the "send" button on the keyboard and the icon button in the actual app, or better yet, unfocus when tapping anywhere but the keyboard?

Comment: Did you try to set Keyboard.dismiss before the alert? inside onMessageSend

Comment: @Sarmad yes I have. It has the same effect

Comment: how about settings a ref, for example 
 ref={ref => this.input = ref}
 onSubmitEditing={() => this.input.blur()} or inside messagesend function, use this.input.blur()

Comment: @Sarmad Still no luck, here is a link to what the output looks like so you can better understand it: [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/310995192)

Comment: This is a weird, Try to use the things i told you inside button onPress of alert.

Comment: Hmm so I found that using onPress = {Keyboard.dismiss} in the icon button does work, but when using it in the messageSend function it does not work.